# JMH: accessing BenchmarkParams from @Setup method of @State class

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

**Is it possible to access `BenchmarkParams` in the `@Setup` of a `@State(Scope.Benchmark)` class, if that class is passed into a `@Benchmark` as parameter?**

Minimal code example (actual usage is more complex, but this reproduces my issue):

```
@State( Scope.Benchmark )
public class Test
{
    @Setup
    public void setUp( BenchmarkParams params ){}

    @Benchmark
    public void nothing( Test test ){}
}
```

There is a basic [JMH sample](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/13ae22114e22/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_31_InfraParams.java), but not where the `@State` is passed into a `@Benchmark` method

I'd like to access `BenchmarkParams` in `@Setup` to retrieve/log per-benchmark configuration data that I create based on JMH `@Param` values

With the sample code, above:

1. Define `@State(Scope.Benchmark)` class named `Test` <--- works
2. Define `@Benchmark` method named `nothing()` <--- works
3. Pass `@State` instance into `@Benchmark` method <--- **FAILS!**

Here is the error:

```
[ERROR]
/Users/.../jmh-benchmarks/target/generated-sources/annotations/test/generated/Test_nothing_jmhTest.java:[390,16]
method setUp in class test.Test cannot be applied to given
types;
  required: org.openjdk.jmh.infra.BenchmarkParams
  found:
org.openjdk.jmh.infra.generated.BenchmarkParams_jmhType,org.openjdk.jmh.infra.generated.BenchmarkParams_jmhType
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Any help welcome!

**[EDIT 1]**

FYI, in my actual code there is also a `@State(Scope.Thread)` class, something more like:

```
@State( Scope.Benchmark )
public abstract class TestBase
{
    @Setup
    public void setUp( BenchmarkParams params ){}
}

@State( Scope.Benchmark )
public class TestImpl extends TestBase
{
    @State( Scope.Thread )
    public static class ThreadState 
    {
            @Setup
            public void setUp( TestImpl state ){}
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void nothing( ThreadState state ){}
}
```

**[EDIT 2]**

As of JMH 1.3 this is no longer a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in question, passing `BenchmarkParams` into `@Setup` of `TestBase`causes JMH build failures

It seems to be related to having [DAGs of @State classes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/13ae22114e22/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_29_StatesDAG.java)

Passing `BenchmarkParams` into a `@State(Scope.Benchmark)` class that is *not* part of the "main" DAG (e.g., `@State(Scope.Benchmark)`->`@State(Scope.Thread)`->`@Benchmark`) branch seems to resolve that problem

For example,

```
@State( Scope.Benchmark )
public abstract class TestBase
{
    @Setup
    public void setUp( BenchmarkParamsState state )
    {
        // do something with state.someParam
    }

    @State( Scope.Benchmark )
    public static class BenchmarkParamsState
    {
        String someParam;

        @Setup
        public void setUp( BenchmarkParams params )
        {
            // set someParam based on contents of params
        }
    }
}

@State( Scope.Benchmark )
public class TestImpl extends TestBase
{
    @State( Scope.Thread )
    public static class ThreadState 
    {
        @Setup
        public void setUp( TestImpl state ){}
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void nothing( ThreadState state ){}
}
```

In addition, because `BenchmarkParamsState` is part of the greater DAG (due to being passed into `@Setup` of `TestBase`) its `@Setup` still occurs once for every `@Benchmark`

**[EDIT]**

As of JMH 1.3 this is no longer a problem